# What surface treatment can turn nickel black?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, electrochemistry, electroplating

**Questions:**

- The detailed surface treatment to turn nickel plated steel black.
- The reaction mechanism of the process.

---

**Methods:**

- (preferred) Anodizing, oxidizing : The only black nickel oxide is $\ce{Ni2O3}$ but I'm not sure if it's suitable for surface protection. I do not know the color or other Ni(II) or Ni(III) compound. There are [nickel blackening solution](https://jaxchemical.com/shop/jax-iron-steel-nickel-blackener/) for sale, but I don't know their ingredients.
- (not preferred) Electroplating onto the existing nickel: US military have a standard to electroplate black nickel ([MIL-P-18317](http://everyspec.com/MIL-SPECS/MIL-SPECS-MIL-P/download.php?spec=MIL-P-18317.018976.pdf)). However this process is quite a fuss.

Comment: Sodium thiocyanate (?) is not an uncommon chemical. https://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/19760021316.pdf (just my 10ct after 90 sec. on google)

Comment: See https://www.finishing.com/330/81.shtml . Also, ferrous metal blackeners that contain alkali selenides or selenous acid (selenium dioxide solution) *might* work. **N.B.** All are fairly toxic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [article](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/19760021316.pdf) provided by [Karl](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/users/17952/karl) has answered the question with electroplating method, which is not preferred but this is the only answer I have.

---

- The method is based on MIL-P-18317. The electroplating solution consists of $\ce{NiSO4, Ni(NH4)2(SO4)2, ZnSO4}$ and $\ce{NaSCN}$

---

- The black nickle coating are $\ce{NiS}$ and $\ce{ZnS}$.
- $\ce{NiS}$ and $\ce{ZnS}$ are deposited by $\ce{M^2+ + H2S -> MS + 2 H+}$.
- $\ce{H2S}$ is generated by $\ce{SCN- + 3H+ + 2e- -> H2S + HCN}$

note: Is reducing thiocyanate a standard method to generate sulfide in electroplating ? I know soluble sulfide salts smells horrible, but it is worth the trouble ? not mentioning the cyanide byproduct, in acidic solution.

---

- Metal $\ce{Ni}$ and $\ce{Zn}$ are also deposited $\ce{M(NH3)2^2+ + 2e- -> M + 2NH3}$.
- The role of $\ce{NH4+}$ is to generate $\ce{M(NH3)2^2+}$ prior to metal deposition.

Comment: You may want to review those chemical formulas.  You have nickel(I) sulfate and a double sulfate with nickel(0). ???

Answer (score 0):

You can use [PVD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physical_vapor_deposition) or [CVD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chemical_vapor_deposition) method. You will get a nano coating of Ni oxides. In PVD chamber you can heat Ni steel with $\ce{N2 + O2}$ or $\ce{Ar + O2}.$